getStreamUserToken cloud function error 'Function must be called while authenticated', though user IS authenticated?
I'm using React Native CLI with Firebase for auth and have installed the stream chat extension, I think correctly. When I call the cloud function getStreamUserToken it just gives me the error 'The function must be called while authenticated.
I'm almost certain it is authenticated. Wondering if I have to set any permissions or something in Cloud Functions?
Have scoured the intermeweb for days for solution... (found flutter example and 99% just about dev tokens)
If anyone has advice or method/steps for RN Cli that would be great!
Here is my code for calling the cloud function:
  ...
  const chatToken = useSelector(state => state.user.chatToken); //null by default

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async authUser => {
      if (authUser && !chatToken) {
        // Ensure user is authenticated
        async function getToken() {
          try {
            // Firebase cloud function to get steam chat token
            console.log('CLOUD FUNCTION INSTIGATED');
            const response = await functions().httpsCallable(
              'ext-auth-chat-getStreamUserToken',
            )();
            console.log('CLOUD FUNCTION COMPLETED');
            console.log('Chat token: ', response.data);

            dispatch(setChatToken(response.data));
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error getting chat token:', error);
            Snackbar.show({
              text: 'Error getting chat token',
              backgroundColor: 'grey',
              textColor: 'white',
            });
          }
        }
        getToken(); // Call getToken only when user is authenticated
      }
      return unsubscribe; // Cleanup function to unsubscribe from the onAuthStateChanged listener
    });
  }, [dispatch, , auth, navigation, chatToken]);

